# A norm inequality $(AB+BA') \leq |A+A'|*B \leq 2|A|*B$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Suppose that A and B are two $n \times n$ matrices.

If $AB+BA'$ and $B$ are both positive definite symmetric matrices, is it true to conclude that $AB+BA' \leq $|A+A'|*B$ \leq 2|A|*B$?

- $A<B$ we mean that $(A-B)$ is negative definite.
- $A'$ means the transpose of matrix $A$.
- $|A|$ indicates the 2-norm of matrix $A$.

Comment: +) by A<B we mean that (A-B) is negative definite

Comment: ++) A' indicates the transpose of matrix A

Comment: +++) by |A| we mean norm-2 of matrix A

Comment: I have typeset this for you. If you right click on an something, you can then click Show Math As >> TeX commands to see how to do this. For instance, the <= symbol can be written as $\leq$ by typing \$\leq\$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Try
$$ A = \pmatrix{1 & -1\cr 1 & 1\cr}, \ B = \pmatrix{2 & 0\cr 0 & 1\cr} $$

Comment: I think this is not a counter example.

Comment: $(AB+BA') = \pmatrix{4 & 1\cr 1 & 2\cr} \leq 2*B \leq 2*1.4142*B$

Comment: $A \leq B$ means $A-B$ is negative semi-definite

Comment: $\pmatrix{4 & 1\cr 1 & 2\cr} - \pmatrix{4 & 0\cr 0 & 2\cr}$ is not negative semidefinite, its eigenvalues are $\pm 1$.

Comment: oh yes
I made a mistake